# Multi language website without duplicating subfolders

Tags: php, mapping, multilingual

I would like to set up a multi language website where the details are being populated from a database.

I have chosen the following format as the best option for me:
http://site.tld/[:language]/[:query]

However, I have some questions and concerns on implementing it.

I have set up my site now as http://site.tld/[:query].

I do not want to have to duplicate all the css, js, images, and other plugin directories.  In this case what is the best option for remapping all the directories within my own php and html files, as well as for other plugin files?  I foresee manually changing all the paths as extremely time consuming and prone to errors.  (ie changing "images/image.jpg" to "../images/image.jpg"

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can have multiple languages within your website without any URL changes.

For a really smooth and easy translation you can use Cloud Translation, it's a free and open-source project from Angry Monkey Cloud: https://github.com/angrymonkeycloud/CloudTranslation.

You should add a reference to jQuery first, then to the CloudTranslation JavaScript file:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.amcapi.com/translation/cloudtranslation-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

And add the configuration within the HTML head as follows:

```
<script type="application/json" id="CloudTranslationConfig">
    {
  "Settings": {
    "DefaultLanguage": "en",
   "UrlLanguageLocation": "", // Here you can set to "Subdirectory" if you want to include the language code in your URL
    "TranslatorProvider": "Azure", // Could be empty if you want to provide the translations manually
    "TranslatorProviderKey": "{Your Microsoft Azure Translator Key}",
    "UrlLanguageLocation": "Subdirectory"
  },
  "Languages": [
    {
      "Code": "en",
      "DisplayName": "English"
    },
    {
      "Code": "de",
      "DisplayName": "Deutsch"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

and add your own custom select (dropdown) having the class "CloudTranslationSelect" to display the list of predefined languages.

More information found on https://www.angrymonkeycloud.com/translation